# Test stripe saved credit cards without using web hooks

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am currently using Laravel Cashier (PHP) and am using the returned `stripe_id` that is saved in my `users` table for future payments. I am not using Stripes or Laravel cashiers subscription functionality as I want more dynamic control over it.

The way it works at the moment for is..

1. Client has an account on my app.
2. They can add a credit card if they like
3. When they do, this generates a subscription of 0/month on Stripe and saves them as a customer.
4. With the returned and saved `stripe_id` in my `users` table I proceed with my own subscription functionality.

Adding the credit card is fine with regard to error handling etc, because I can simply use the test cards stripe provide.

However, once the customer has been added to my Stripe account I have no way of testing that customer for future billing.

I have tried adding a declined card in the stripe dashboard, e.g. 4000 0000 0000 0002, but nothing happens, and when I check the console I can see the error below. This is understandable but I was hoping in test mode it would allow me to add it.

[image]

I know I can use web hooks but it just seems impractical to me for what Im looking to do. It would be frustrating to test on my local machine and I would still need to be able to change the credit card to a failed one to send the correct web hook. I dont want to rely on Stripe web hook testing as it wouldnt be in sync with my process as I would have no control over the customer_id etc for testing.

Here is my code for charging the customer. As you can see I use the `stripe_id` to charge.

The other errors work, but the only one I really want to test is the card, so that if it expires or there are insufficient funds my app will know

```
 $stripeID = $this->billing->getStripeID($userID);

try {
    \Stripe\InvoiceItem::create( [
        'customer'    => $stripeID,
        'amount'      => $totalAmount,
        'currency'    => 'eur',
        'description' => 'Test Charge'
    ] );


    $invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::create( [
        'customer' => $stripeID
    ] );

    $invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::retrieve( $invoice->id );
    $charge = $invoice->pay();

} catch(Card $e) {
    // error handling
} catch (RateLimit $e) {
    // error handling
} catch (InvalidRequest $e) {
    // error handling
} catch (Authentication $e) {
    // error handling
} catch (ApiConnection $e) {
    // error handling
} catch (Base $e) {
    // error handling
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // error handling
}
```

Comment: your first `catch` ... `} catch(Card $e) {` should catch is if the card is declined, or expired right?

Comment: yes, and in theory im sure it would work fine in live mode but having no way to test it is the problem. I would like to successfully add a card in test mode , and then let it expire so during my charging functionality it sees that it has expired

Comment: This link has a card # and instructions for `testing payment failures` https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/testing

Comment: Thank you @cmorrissey, I found the card in that section that I was able to add into Stripe to test as declined. Not sure how I missed it before. Feel free to add as an answer.